# Calling variable outside of class

Tags: java, variables, methods, scope

I'm trying to call three variables that are outside the scope of my method. 
The Application class calls the `Calculator` class to conduct the basic operations.

I know there are several ways to do this, but what is the most basic way to call the variable operation and methods `addNumbers`, `subtractNumbers`, `multiplyNumbers`, and `divideNumbers` from the `calculate()` method within the `Calcuator` class?

Code for the Application class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int quantity1;
    int quantity2;
    int operation;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please select one of the following operations: ");
    System.out.println("1- Addition, 2-Subtraction, 3-Multiplication, 4-Division, 5-exit: ");
    operation = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the first quantity: ");
    quantity1 = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the second quantity: ");
    quantity2 = userInput.nextInt();
    Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();
    myCalculator.calculate();
  }

  public void calculate () {
    switch(operation) {
      case 1:
        System.out.println(addNumbers(quantity1, quantity2));
      case 2:
        System.out.println(subtractNumbers(quantity1, quantity2));
      case 3:
        System.out.println(multiplyNumbers(quantity1, quantity2));
      case 4:
        System.out.println(divideNumbers(quantity1, quantity2));
      case 5:
        System.exit(0); 
    }    
  }
}
```

Code for the Calculator class:

```
package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
  public int addNumbers(int A, int B){
    return A+B;
  }
  public int subtractNumbers(int A, int B){
    return A - B;
  }
  public int multiplyNumbers(int A, int B){
    return A * B;
  }
  public int divideNumbers(int A, int B){
    return A / B;
  }
}
```

*Edit: I need to call the calculate method from the Application class.

Comment: You cannot invoke `calculate()` by an instance of `Calculator`,  it belongs to class `Application`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will change that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand completly why you structured your code as it is now. From my point of view the main application is responsible for reading the three input values (two operands and one operator). It can also hold an instance of Calculator.

Assume that the calculate method is moved to the Calculator itself and takes those three values as parameters. Then the calculator can execute an operation (based on the operator/ switch) statement and return the result.

As you are passing now the three inputs from the main application to the Calculator class, this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
        private static int quantity1;
        private static int quantity2;
        private static int operation;
        private Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please select one of the following operations: ");
        System.out.println("1- Addition, 2-Subtraction, 3-Multiplication, 4-Division, 5-exit: ");
        operation = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the first quantity: ");
        quantity1 = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the second quantity: ");
        quantity2 = userInput.nextInt();


        new Application().calculate();
    }

    public void calculate() {

        switch (operation) {
            case 1:

                System.out.println(myCalculator.addNumbers(quantity1, quantity2));

            case 2:
                System.out.println(myCalculator.subtractNumbers(quantity1, quantity2));

            case 3:
                System.out.println(myCalculator.multiplyNumbers(quantity1, quantity2));

            case 4:
                System.out.println(myCalculator.divideNumbers(quantity1, quantity2));

            case 5:
                System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

- moved your local variables quantity1,quantity2 and operation outside `main()` and make them static variables
- moved `myCalculator` outside as well.
- invoke addNumbers, substractNumbers by `myCalculator`
- Didn't change anyhting in class `Calculator`

Here's my output:

```
Please select one of the following operations: 
1- Addition, 2-Subtraction, 3-Multiplication, 4-Division, 5-exit: 
1
Please enter the first quantity: 
2
Please enter the second quantity: 
2
4
0
4
1
```

**Attention**:
your `switch statement` is not working, it prints all operations results  because you didn't provide any `break` to any cases, that's why all operations had been displayed, it is called `blocks fall through`. you need to do your only work to fix. Here's a[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) can help you

Answer (score 0):

I believe the calculate() method should have been in the Calculator class and not the Application class, as per your question in the code fragment.

Use instance variables instead of method local variables and mark them as private (also static if accessed from a static method). This way you can set the values using the appropriate setter methods and fetch using corresponding getter methods in your Calculator class, as they would be public methods.

This is a standard practice, referred to as JavaBean convention.

Answer (score 0):

The basic and elegant way is to write a constructor in your Calculator class.

- In main method, simply pass parameters `operation`, `quantity1`, and `quantity2` into constructor when you instantiate a new object `myCalculator`.
- Instead of putting your `calculate()` method in `Application` class and as mentioned in your description, `calculate()` method should goes in `Calculator` class.
- Invoke `calculate()` method declared within `Calculator` class

Snippet of `main(String[] args)` method

```
Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator(operation, quantity1, quantity2);
myCalculator.calculate();
```

Code for the Calculator class:

```
package calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    // Add three private variable to indicate operation and operands
    private int operand1;
    private int operand2;
    private int operation;

    // You should write a constructor to take parameters read from Scanner
    public Calculator(int operation, int quantity1, int quantity2){
        operand1 = quantity1;
        operand2 = quantity2;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public int addNumbers(int A, int B){
        return A+B;
    }
    public int subtractNumbers(int A, int B){
        return A - B;
    }
    public int multiplyNumbers(int A, int B){
        return A * B;
    }
    public int divideNumbers(int A, int B){
        return A / B;
    }

    // Your calculator method should goes here
    public void calculate(){
        switch(operation){
        case 1:
            System.out.println(addNumbers(operand1, operand2));
            break;
        case 2:
             System.out.println(subtractNumbers(operand1, operand2));
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println(multiplyNumbers(operand1, operand2));
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println(divideNumbers(operand1, operand2));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```